# jgroups - callRemoteMethodsWithFuture blocks

Tags: jgroups

I have a use-case wherein the coordinator is chosen by the application(using Custom MembershipPolicy and selecting a node configured to be the master) and a loss of the master should not take so long to be realized by the client nodes that are making RPCs (assume that the success/failure of the operation depends on the presence/absence of the master). Without the callRemoteMethods(), I can specify an acceptable timeout in the RequestOptions but this would increase the RTT if I have say 100 requests that are in queue. Hence I use callRemoteMethodsWithFuture() to avoid network transmission time between several RPCs. The problem however is, with SEQUENCER in the stack, callRemoteMethodsWithFuture() is blocking until the message is forwarded to the coordinator. Coordinator loss during such situations make the call blocking until a view change occurs. This is something I want to avoid in my application (since coordinator loss equates to master loss and a master loss has to be identified sooner by the caller). Removing SEQUENCER is not an option. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: This is the expected behavior with the API. I have discussed this further with the author of JGroups, which can be followed at [Jgroups groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jgroups-dev/aFjJSrFpa1Q)